# error when importing robotframework result into xray

Tags: rest, curl, robotframework, jira, x-ray

I want to import the result of my execution (robot framework) with REST API into JIRA. I used the following command

```
curl --insecure   -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -D- -p -F "file=@outputXX.xml"  "https://portail.agir.orange.com/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/robot?projectKey=MY"
```

I have this error:

> {"error":"Cannot add label with invalid validation result!"}

This error is not clear enough to know exactly the problem's origin.
Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://iwconnect.com/xray-integration-with-robot-testing-framework/

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason of this error:
the label refers to the TAG in robot framework
my TAG is JIRA was CONNECT_ID or in my test the tag is CONNECT ID , the space caused this error
I hope my answer helps other!